# Showing that the quotient function is primitive recursive

Tags: primitive-recursion

I'm asked to show that the quotient function is primitive recursive. I know that the operation of integer division $div$ is not total, as it is not defined when the denominator is zero, and a recursive function has to be total by definition.

So I could give a function $div'$ and define a value for the case that the denominator is zero: 
$div'(x,y) = 0$ if $y = 0$, otherwise $div'(x,y) = div(x,y)$. But this is still not primitive recursive because of $div$. How can I go about proving that the quotient function is actually primitive recursive? Should it somehow be built from scratch? Any help would be appreciated.